# MacOS automated screenshot tool

Tags: macos

On my WIN laptop, I use AutomaticScreenshotter app to capture my screens so I know, what I was doing through the week for the business purposes.

Now I am experimenting with MacOS (Monterey) and I really miss a tool like this (up to the point to throw the machine away if I won`t find the tool).

Most of the tools have the issue, that it captures only the main screen.

I need the following set of tools:

- capture all connected screens to one image
- Set capture interval
- set dynamic name of the file
- (optional) the ability to sort the files to folders (e.g. dynamically create Year/Month/day/time.jpg
- (optional, but largely appreciated) autodelete of images older than X
- system autostart
- toolbar icon so I know it is running
- reliability - I really need it to work even after waking up the machine from sleep/hibernation

I tried InstantShot! (captures only the main screen)
I tried shell script executing screencapture utility (captures only the main screen and browsing through man pages showed no parameter to just capture all at once

I have seen some very old article (10y ago) about some utility Grab, but that utility is nonexistent on my Monterey machine

Do you know some MacOS app, that would achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Software requests are off-topic, but you could do most of this with Applescript, saved as a service. Look at https://ss64.com/osx/screencapture.html which is the structure behind Grab & the key-commanded capture modes. The only thing to note is that to capture both screens, you need to use 'rectangle' mode with the entire screen area. You'd need to also devise a loop for numbering/tagging. At simplest `do shell script "screencapture -R 0,0,5120,1440  /Users/me/Desktop/test.png"` will capture both screens on a dual 2k setup.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try, but that is not ideal as well. I usually use 3 monitor setup, but it is also a laptop, so in the case of disconnecting the monitors, I don't want to have screenshot of the size of an elephant when there will be just a small 1 screen captured. Or the rectangle feature trims the unused space? Additionally, this must works automatically so I don't need to adjust the rectangle in case of a different monitor grid setup connected.

And sorry for OT, didn't know, felt like the best place to ask because of the community, if you know better place, please suggest.

Comment: Evidently, grab has been replaced: https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-use-mac-os-x-grab-utility-to-take-screenshots/#:~:text=In%20macOS%20Mojave%20and%20above%2C%20the%20Screenshot%20app%20replaces%20the,open%20the%20new%20Screenshot%20app.

Comment: @EricS - you just don't need the screenshot function to be a separate app any more. All the functionality of Grab and more has been incorporated in the new Cmd/Shift/5 version

Comment: Thanks for the help, now is there any way to automate the screenshot app? I tried to search for it, but it seems like Screenshot.app does not have terminal interface ...

Comment: I gave you the syntax & a basic script. All you need now is a bit of research.

Comment: Hi Tetsujin, thanks for your reply. As I wrote, the "screencapture" rectangle function is not the best fit, as the machine is laptop and I have multiple configuration connected, including the layout, so I would need to adjust the rectangle all the time or do something really big to accommodate multiple layouts, which would be bad if you disconnect all and you would have only 1 fullHD display on like 7000x7000 canvas. Or you can confirm, that the screencapture TRIMMS the blank space? That is why I have asked, if Screenshot.app actually can be automated somehow as that is a different app. Thx!